# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder

I have defined and trained an autoencoder model as follow:

```
input_enc = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, seq_len, n_features), name='encoder_input')
first_enc = LSTM(32, activation='tanh', dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, name='encoder_first_layer')(input_enc)
if output_dropout:
    first_enc = Dropout(0.2)(first_enc)
encoded, hidden_state, cell_state = LSTM(14, activation='tanh', dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False, return_state=True , stateful=True, name='encoded')(first_enc)
decoder_input = RepeatVector(28, name='repeatVector')(encoded)
first_dec = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_first_layer')(decoder_input)
out_decoder = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_output_layer')(first_dec)

autoencoder_model = Model(input_enc, out_decoder)
encoder_model = Model(inputs=input_enc, outputs=[encoded, hidden_state, cell_state])
```

The input shape to Autoencoder model is `(n_samples, seq_len=28, n_features=1)` and `batch_size = 138` 
After trying the Autoencoder I load the encoder part and use it as an input to another model.

```
input_layer = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, seq_len, n_features), name='ae_prediction_input')
encoder_first_layer = encoder.layers[1](input_layer)
encoded_layer, h_state, c_state = encoder.layers[2](encoder_first_layer)
first_layer = Dense(24, input_dim=28, activation=activation, name="first_dense_layer")(h_state)
if dropout:
    first_layer = Dropout(0.2, name="first_dropout_layer")(first_layer)
second_layer = Dense(12, activation=activation, name="second_dense_layer")(first_layer)
if dropout:
    second_layer = Dropout(0.2, name="snd_dropout_layer")(second_layer)
out = Dense(1, name='output_layer')(second_layer)
new_model = Model(input_layer, out)
new.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=rmsprop_optimizer)
history = new_model.fit(train_data, train_y, epochs=5, callbacks=[earlyStopping], batch_size=batch_size
                        , validation_data=(validation_data, validation_y), shuffle=False)
```

At first I was trying to use encoder's input layer but the gives me this error: `ValueError: Layer encoder_first_layer was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'eras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer'>.Full input: [<keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x13b97ced0>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.` So instead, I am creating a new input layer and on top of that I am adding the first LSTM layer of the pre-trained encoder mode. When I try to fit the `new_model`, the first epoch runs and at the end of the first epoch I'm getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'encoder_input' with dtype float and shape [138,28,1]
     [[{{node encoder_input}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[138,28,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

What is the problem? Why the first epochs runs and after that it remembers that encoder input layer is not receiving values?

**UPDATE**: It seems like the issue is related to validation data. At the end of last epoch, Keras checks the validation data and runs it. That's where it gives this error.

Comment: Can you please provide the full code example. By full, I mean how you run this graph (e.g. how you use model.fit or model.train_on_batch)?

Comment: One reason I can think of is, especially given that the error appears at the end of first epoch, since you are specifically specifying `batch_shape`, your last batch of inputs probably has less data (i.e. less than 138 entries), which can raise the exception you observed. You can try 2 things:
1. Instead of `batch_shape` use `shape` where you don't need to define the batch size
2. If you have large amount of data, just ignore the last batch of data.

Comment: @thushv89 Thanks for your comment. the `batch_size=138` divides both training and validation data. `training.shape=(49956,28,1), validation.shape=(16422,28,1), test.shape=(8004,28,1)`. I tried to remove `validation_data=(validation_data, validation_y)` from `fit()`, it works and trains the model with no error! But then it failes to run `new_model.evaluate(train_data, train_y, verbose=0, batch_size=batch_size)` with the same error as before.

Comment: @thushv89 It complains to feed data to the first layer of pre-trained encoder, `encoder_input`, which I haven't load it to create the `new_model`.  Instead, I am using a new `Input()` layer. Is that wrong?

Comment: Hmm, the other reason I can think of is, the way you are creating the prediction model (i.e. `new_model`) needs to change. Instead of getting `model.layers[x]`, try creating a fresh layer e.g. `LSTM(....)` and then use `model.layers[x].get_weights()` and use that to `set_weights` of the fresh layer in the prediction model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @thushv89 answer I fixed the code as follow:

```
encoder = load_model(encoder_path)

input_enc = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, seq_len, n_features), name='ae_prediction_input')
first_enc = LSTM(encoder.layers[1].units, activation=activation, dropout=encoder.layers[1].dropout, recurrent_dropout=encoder.layers[1].recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True, stateful=encoder.layers[1].stateful)(input_enc)
encoded, hidden_state, cell_state = LSTM(encoder.layers[2].units, activation=activation, dropout=encoder.layers[2].dropout, recurrent_dropout=encoder.layers[2].recurrent_dropout , return_sequences=False, stateful=encoder.layers[2].stateful)(first_enc)

first_dense = Dense(24, input_dim=28, activation=activation,name="first_dense_layer")(h_state)
if dropout:
    first_dense = Dropout(0.2, name="first_dropout_layer")(first_dense)
second_layer = Dense(12, activation=activation, name="second_dense_layer")(first_dense)
if dropout:
    second_layer = Dropout(0.2, name="snd_dropout_layer")(second_layer)
out = Dense(1, name='output_layer')(second_layer)

model = Model(input_enc, out)
model.layers[1].set_weights(encoder.layers[1].get_weights())
model.layers[2].set_weights(encoder.layers[2].get_weights())
```